# Stripe form not submitting

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, stripe-payments

My stripe form is not submitting. When I press submit it goes to page cannot be displayed. I replaced the route code to resolve to an echo "test"; and the post request shows the echo. Any help would be appreciated. This code is from a tutorial http://www.sitepoint.com/selling-downloads-stripe-laravel/

Route

```
Route::get('/buy/{id}', function($id)
{
$download = Download::find($id);    
return View::make('buy', array('download' => $download));
});

Route::post('/buy/{id}', function($id)
{
Stripe::setApiKey(Config::get('laravel-stripe::stripe.sk_test_aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'));

$download = Download::find($id);
$token = Input::get('stripeToken');
// Charge the card
try {
    $charge = Stripe_Charge::create(array(
        "amount" => $download->price,
        "currency" => "gbp",
        "card" => $token,
        "description" => 'Order: ' . $download->name)
    );
    // If we get this far, we've charged the user successfully
    Session::put('purchased_download_id', $download->id);
    return Redirect::to('confirmed');

} catch(Stripe_CardError $e) {
    // Payment failed
    return Redirect::to('buy/'.$id)->with('message', 'Your payment has failed.');       
}
});
```

View

```
@extends('layouts.default')

@section('content')

<h1>Your Order</h1>

<h2>{{ $download->name }}</h2>

<p>£{{ ($download->price/100) }}</p>

<form action="" method="POST" id="payment-form" role="form">

<input type="hidden" name="did" value="{{ $download->id }}" />

<div class="payment-errors alert alert-danger" style="display:none;"></div>

<div class="form-group">
<label>
  <span>Card Number</span>
  <input type="text" size="20" data-stripe="number" class="form-control input-lg" />
</label>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label>
  <span>CVC</span>
  <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="cvc" class="form-control input-lg" />
</label>
</div>

<div class="form-group">  
<label>
  <span>Expires</span>      
</label>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
    <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp-month" class="input-lg" placeholder="MM" />
  </div>  
  <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
    <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="exp-year" class="input-lg" placeholder="YYYY" />
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Submit Payment</button>
</div>
</form>

@stop
```

Comment: You shouldn't pass any parameter to the post route, use `Input::get('did')` instead.

Comment: @phaberest I am confused why and not following you why I cannot leave the code as it is.

Comment: Forget it, maybe I'm just confused using too many frameworks in the last month.

Have you tried forcing the `action`instead of leaving it blank?

Comment everything in the post route and try with a `dd('submitted');` to see if it gets to it.

Comment: you should have got `parameter 1 missing` when you try to post the form. aren't you getting it?

Comment: @itachi I am not getting any errors. The js is not coming through. I tested in js and I should be getting a console log message and I am not. I checked the js file and it is linked.

Comment: @itachi Here is a screen shot with the parameter passed http://postimg.org/image/86t9eutn3/

Comment: @itachi correction: I tested in firefox with firebug in console log

Comment: yup the error is coming in. enable `debug => true` in `config/app.php`

Comment: @itachi that solved half of it, it was set to false. Now I get an stripe api key error that it is not set. Here is what I have. Stripe::setApiKey(Config::get('laravel-stripe::sk_test_4Pr7KmElLtZS3C56MN0OTEqx'));